# lwuit.io.Storage clears after closing application

Tags: java-me, storage, lwuit, externalizable

I'm trying to use lwuit.io.Storage, it works fine while application is running (I can do crud) but it's data clears after closing the application. 
I've considered:

- registering my class with "Util.register("Car", Car.class);" in "initVars()" method;
- implementing "Externalizable" interface in "Car" class. // "getObjectId()" method returns "Car"
- calling "Storage.init("myProjectName");" in MainMIDlet class
- checking to make sure Storage is initialized properly with "Storage.isInitialized()" in MainMIDlet class
- I'm storing my "car" objects with a Vector, using:

  ```
  Car c = new Car("ford", 1918);

  Vector v = (Vector) Storage.getInstance().readObject("cars");
  if (v == null) {
      v = new Vector();
  }
  v.addElement(c);
  Storage.getInstance().writeObject("cars", v);

  Vector test = (Vector) Storage.getInstance().readObject("cars");
  if (test.lastElement() instanceof Car){
     Car c1 = (Car) test.lastElement();
     System.err.println(c1);
  }
  ```
- **avoiding** call "Storage.getInstance().clearStorage();" anywhere in the code!
- "Storage.getInstance().listEntries();" returns one element array containing "cars" String (even after restarting application).

[this](http://ideone.com/SycCY) is my simple "car" class.

any idea what I'm missing / doing wrong here?

thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to test with a "String" instead of "Vector", it worked fine. the string preserved in the Storage after closing the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, that was a stupid mistake,

The problem was in implementing Externalizable inteface, 
I was calling "**Util**.writeUTF(name);" in externalize() method, and trying to read it with "**stream**.readUTF()" in internalize method.

simply replaced "**Util**.writeUTF(name)" with "**stream**.writeUTF(name)".

and it worked out.